# Trig Word Problem - Angle of Elevation - Missing Side

Tags: trigonometry

Raj is at the top of a lighthouse $420 m$ from the coast. He measures the angle of elevation to the top of the cliff to be $28^{\circ}$ and the angle of depression to the bottom of the cliff to be $18^{\circ}$.  How high is the cliff?  Give your answer to the nearest $m$.

I can't seem to draw a triangle that matches this description of a coast and a lighthouse.

Comment: Im not understanding the question. So is the lighthouse on the cliff? Angle of depression from where to where?

Comment: Yea. Thats my problem - it doesn't make sense to me. I tried drawing it but wasn't sure how to draw it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It must be that the lighthouse is offshore on a rock.  His point of view is a ways above sea level because of the height of the lighthouse.  The cliff is the shoreline.  He looks down to the edge of the ocean and up to the top of the cliff, which are one above the other vertically.